# How to use Amazon S3 Transfer Utility in android without Cognito or Identit Pools?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I use Amazon S3 Transfer Utility in android without Cognito or Identit Pools? I want to use just a user ID and key to access a S3 bucket. I try the following code, but it does not work.

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID, AWS_PASSWORD);

AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds);

TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, context);

transferUtility.upload(
                BUCKET,       
                key,          
                file           
        );
```

Whats is wrong?

Comment: What other way are you trying to use TransferUtility? It not recommended to hard code your credentials in an app. What is the use case you are trying to achieve?

Comment: you may check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49007899/1288725) which is using access key instead of cognito or pool.