# AWS S3 Android SDK where do you specify Access key and secret?

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I'm following : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html  ....... where in the android call do you specify the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key?? How does it know I can access if I don't provide them?

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                context,    /* get the context for the application */
                "COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL",    /* Identity Pool ID */
                Regions.US_EAST_1           /* Region for your identity pool--US_EAST_1 or EU_WEST_1*/
        );

        // Create an S3 client
        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);

        TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, context);

        File file = new File(filePath);

        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
                BuildConfig.S3_BUCKET,     /* The bucket to upload to */
                "uploads",    /* The key for the uploaded object */
                file        /* The file where the data to upload exists */
        );

         observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener().
           ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create `AmazonS3Client` with access key and secret key as mentioned below:

```
        AmazonS3Client s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new AWSCredentials() {
            @Override
            public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
                return "accesskeyhere";
            }

            @Override
            public String getAWSSecretKey() {
                return "secretkeyhere";
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am unable to find the accesskey from S3 bucket. Where can I find the keys?

Comment: @Priya : you need to create it. reference: https://medium.com/@shamnad.p.s/how-to-create-an-s3-bucket-and-aws-access-key-id-and-secret-access-key-for-accessing-it-5653b6e54337